# Escaping question mark in Apache regex conf

Tags: regex, apache

I need a regex for setting access level of certain URLs in Apache httpd.conf. I've manage to set everything up and the rules is working as expected.

But when I try to set up rules for URLs with question marks I don't get any match with my Regex. I can't escape the question mark.

Matching URL `/?token=averylongtoken1234`

My rule is:

```
<LocationMatch "^\/\?token=[a-zA-Z\d%]*">
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</LocationMatch>
```

If I change the regex to `^\/token=[a-zA-Z\d%]*` the URL `/token=averylongtoken1234` is working as expected.

Comment: `^` asserts the position at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Does anyone know how to escape the questionmark or isn't it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`LocationMatch` directive doesn't match query string.** As an alternative you can use `mod_rewrite` rule for this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)token=[a-zA-Z\d%]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=401]
```

Comment: How do I return a 401 if the condition not met?